# Multi-audio manipulation

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm trying to do some fairly "advanced" audio manipulation. I thought it'd be a no brainer setting but that seems to not be the case.

Basically, I was wondering if anyone knows of a software (and if not, then how to do it by coding) that allows you to assign each running application to an audio port? I attached a diagram to help explain this since a picture is worth a thousand words!

[image: Visual diagram]

So as You can see, I want to use more than one audio port at a time and then assign my application audios to the individual ports as I please.

This would be super helpful since My "beast of a computer" usually has more than one person using it at a time.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get install pavucontrol`

This is a GTK volume mixer for pulseaudio

In contrast to classic mixer tools this one allows you to control both the volume of hardware devices and of each playback stream separately.

https://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/pavucontrol/

Comment: Thanks for the post @cmak.fr, however I've already tried this. On my system if I plug the head phones in, it auto routes from speakers to the head phones. In the `pavucontrol` it shows my "line out" (a.k.a. my speakers) and my "head phones" as a drop down toggle where I pick one or the other.

Secondly, the applications audio out tab doesnt allow me to pick which audio to go to ( I have a third audio out thats HDMI, but I dont want to use that). They simply play to either speakers or headphones.

Comment: use command `aplay -l` in terminal to get list of alsa playback devices. headphones and speakers may have to share one output device and cannot be used independently. If there are 2 analog audio devices, might be able to turn off ALSA 'auto-mute' setting and have 2 independent channels.